# Replace all occurences of a char except if it is the last character in a string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I'm looking for a regex which will replace all occurrences of a char in a string except if it is last char:
E.g.: if I want to replace A  ->  B

```
11A22A33A   -> 11B22B33A
11A22A33    -> 11B22B33
11A22       -> 11B22
11A         -> 11A
A           -> A
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
'11A22A33A'.replace(/A(?!$)/g, 'B');  // "11B22B33A"
```